# How can I iterate child text nodes (not descendants) in ElementTree?

Tags: python, elementtree

Given an element like this

```
<A>
    hello

    <annotation> NOT part of text </annotation>

    world
</A>
```

how can I get just the child text nodes (like XPath `text()`), using `ElementTree`?

Both `iter()` and `itertext()` are tree walkers, which include all descendant nodes.  There is no immediate child iterator that I'm aware of.  Plus, `iter()` only finds *elements*, anyway (it is after all, ElementTree), so can't be used to collect text nodes as such.

I understand that there's a library called `lxml` which provides better XPath support, but I'm asking here before adding another dependency.  (Plus I'm very new to Python so I might be missing something obvious.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You find the text of your example somewhat counter-intuitively in three attributes:

- A.text for "hello"
- annotation.text for "NOT part of text"
- annotation.tail for "world"

(whitespace omitted). This is somewhat cumbersome. However, something along these lines should help:

```
 import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

 xml = """
 <A>
     hello

     <annotation> NOT part of text </annotation>

     world
 </A>"""


 doc = et.fromstring(xml)


 def all_texts(root):
     if root.text is not None:
         yield root.text
     for child in root:
         if child.tail is not None:
             yield child.tail


 print list(all_texts(doc))
```

Comment: Thanks!  This works perfectly.  I had a feeling the odd `tail` property could be used here.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function similar inspired by the accepted answer (from deets) that I found helpful, that concatenates all text within a node:

```py
def get_text(node: ET.Element):
    '''Gets text out of an XML Node'''

    # Get initial text
    text = node.text if node.text else ""
    # Get all text from child nodes recursively
    for child_node in node:
        text += self._get_text(child_node)
    # Get text that occurs after child nodes
    text += node.tail if node.tail else ""
    return text
```