# Extract text from XML node that comes after child node

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm trying to parse an XML document with nodes that have some text, then declare a child node, and then have more text.  For example, the second "post" element in the XML below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <post>
        this is some text
    </post>
    <post>
        here is some more text
        <quote> and a nested node </quote>
        and more text after the nested node
    </post>
</data>
```

I used the following code to try to print out the text of each node:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:
    print (child.text)
```

But unfortunately the only output is:

```
this is some text
here is some more text
```

Note that I'm missing the text `and more text after the nested node`.

So,

1. Is this valid XML?
2. If yes, how can I use ElementTree or another Python XML library to achieve the desired parse?
3. If no, any suggestions to parse the XML short of writing my own parser?

Answer (score 4):

Ah, found the answer here: [How can I iterate child text nodes (not descendants) in ElementTree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26869875/how-can-i-iterate-child-text-nodes-not-descendants-in-elementtree)

Basically I have to use the `.tail` attribute of the child node to access the text that was missing before.